# Android Studio Gradle Error: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android

I'm getting this error when trying to build my project in Android Studio (I'm trying to migrate from Eclipse):
  Output:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl; at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
```

after googling and checking stackoverflow the most likely cause is duplicate library references.
I have a number of libraries in my project such as Facebook SDK, SlidingMenu, etc. that required android-support-v4.jar, so I copied that into my main project's /libs folder and subsequently removed it from all the other projects libs folder. Then I went to "Open Module Settings" and added the support-v4 as a library dependency for the libraries that needed it (e.g. Facebook SDK).
Then clean project -> run but I'm still getting this multiple dex files error

running `gradle -q dependencies` shows:

```
+--- project :facebook-android-sdk-3.5.1:facebook
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:+ -> 19.1.0
+--- project :SlidingMenu:library
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:+ -> 19.1.0
```

Is that okay? If I remove this library dependency in the Module Settings then I will get even more errors while trying to compile my project

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In your build.gradle file try adding the following block inside your android block.

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Comment: YES!  I wasted the past 3 hours trying to figure this out; this is the answer that worked.

Comment: Am directly importing one project from eclipse(ADT) to studio in eclipse its working fine while importing that project with support libreary projects in to studio getting error multiple dex files found please help and provide solution

Comment: Hi. Does anyone know why this works. It's nice to know the solution to my problem, but I'm curious about the reason.

Comment: You should mention that it must be inside the android {} block in  build.gradle file.

Answer (score 3):

Just a Clean Build worked for me ,
Just do this in Android Studio:

> Got to Build > Clean Project

[See image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKhuP.png)

Answer (score 3):

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

and

```
Got to Build > Clean Project
```

and

```
Got to Build > Rebuild Project
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is:

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I did not pay attention to the rules of this site