# Android Studio Gradle build error due to multiple dex files

Tags: android, build, gradle

I got these errors in my project but I have no idea what's the problem.

Below is my errors shown:

Error Code:

```
2
```

Output:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

This is my module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'iyh.queensbase.my.inyourhand'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}
dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      compile project(':facebook')
}
```

Comment: This will help you. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059719/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define

Comment: @Aravindan - that's for Eclipse.

Comment: @Kristy Welsh - ohh.. I am sorry. May I know that linked page accepted answer doesn't clear this problem in Android Studio.? Because mostly that mulitiple dex problem came by adding multiple same dependencies to the lib. Am I right.?

Comment: @Aravindan Hello, is my question clearer now? I really wish to get a solution. Hope you can help me out too. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes! I found my solution! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851103/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define

Comment: @Sabrina - thats great.! I just now seen your comment and try to give the same page you posted above. Its okay. Share us how you solved your problem. That will help others too.