# I want to fix this error in android studio

Tags: android, database, android-studio, parse-platform, runtime-error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio Gradle Error: Multiple dex files define](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851103/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define)

Comment: Make sure you don't have 2 jars in your libs folder for facebook. Keep only the newest version.