# renderscriptSupportModeEnabled is giving an error in android studio

Tags: android

I am getting error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

when I add the line below in gradle:

```
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

How can I fix the issue?I really appreciate any help.

Comment: What renderscriptTargetApi value do your have?

Comment: renderscriptTargetApi 22

Comment: Make it 19 and try again.

Comment: still get the same error..

Comment: What's your gradle version?

Comment: gardle:2.2.1  and android plugin:1.2.3

Answer (score 2):

```
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

will add extra dependencies to your project. These might be conflicting with other dependencies you are using in your app.

For me, the support-annotations was the problem, so I exclude them like so:

```
// fix! for renderscript support
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

NOTE: [Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility) and [Android Studio Gradle Error: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851103/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define) , are related to this problem.