# Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;

Tags: android

I've been dealing with this error from two weeks and its driving me nuts please help:

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2 and when im trying to build the APK a get this error:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

And here's the gradle file code:

```
dependencies {
    //compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.2.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-1.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.5.3'
    compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.1')
            {
                exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts',
                        module: 'bolts-tasks'
                exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts',
                        module: 'bolts-applinks'
            }

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile files('libs/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.estimote:sdk:0.9.7@aar'
    compile ('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0+')
            {
                exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-android'
            }
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

    compile 'com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Gradle Error: Multiple dex files define](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851103/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define)

Comment: It didn't work now i have 10 more errors like this: Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbolts/AggregateException;

Comment: Try [googling that error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Uncaught+translation+error%3A+java.lang.IllegalArg%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BumentException&oq=Uncaught+translation+error%3A+java.lang.IllegalArg%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BumentException&aqs=chrome..69i57.815j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).