# Android Gradle failed Multiple dex files define okhttp

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.3.0'
    compile('com.github.eoinsha:JavaPhoenixChannels:0.2') {
        exclude module: 'groovy-all'
    }
}
```

And the following dependency tree:

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.3.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0 (*)
|    \--- com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.4.0
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0 -> 1.13.0
\--- com.github.eoinsha:JavaPhoenixChannels:0.2
     +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.3
     |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
     |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.3
     \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1
          \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1 -> 3.8.0 (*)
```

I get this error while trying to build the project:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lokhttp3/internal/ws/WebSocketReader$FrameCallback;
```

This is supposedly caused by the presence of two different versions of the okhttp library on the classpath:

- 3.4.1 by `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws` which is a dependency of `JavaPhoenixChannels`
- 3.8.0 by retrofit

Gradle should be able to automatically resolve this, so I wonder what's the probelm.
I tried to fix it by excluding `okhttp` and `okhttp-ws` from their respective first class dependencies and compile them separately but that doesn't seem to help.

Some explanation on why such errors would pop up is also appreciated.

Comment: did you add  defaultConfig { multiDexEnabled true } in build.gradle file in app module ?   then clean the project and try to build again.

Comment: @RohitPadma That seems irrelevant here. I'm not running into method limit issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility/21100040

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851103/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define

Comment: Starting from okhttp 3.5 okhttp-ws is part of okhttp itself... Take a source of this library and compile it by yourself... You may also try to exclude okhttp-ws, but there is a chance that the version in okhttp 3.8.0 has no compatible interface

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar Already seen those question but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Selvin Thanks! solved the issue. You could consider writing this as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Selvin in the comments, the issue is caused by the fact that `okhtt-ws` has been moved inside the core project since version 3.5 and hence specifying both a newer version of the `okhttp` and an old version of `okhttp-ws` would result in two different copies of the `okhttp-ws` library ending up on the classpath. To gradle, these would be different libraries using the same package hierarchy and hence it won't exclude one automatically.

TL;DR the error is fixed by excluding the `okhttp-ws` dependency as it is already available in version 3.8 of the `okhttp` itself:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
compile('com.github.eoinsha:JavaPhoenixChannels:0.2') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp-ws'
}
```