# ByteCode to dex conversion

Tags: android

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/androidquery/util/Constants;
```

I have followed every `stackoverflow` question on this but none of it solved my problem.I am still getting the error.

[Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059719/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define)

[Android Studio Gradle Error: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851103/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define)

[Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

```
//apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.andromeda.kunalbhatia.demo.hungamaplayer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
}
```

Comment: Can u post your gradle?

Comment: @Raghavendra please have a look.I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you use two lib that inside use the same transitive dependencies.

Review your dependencies on build.gradle, and use `exclude` tag for not repeat dependencies. (You should update the post adding your dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

try by adding

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

in defautconfig{}
in gradle

Answer (score 0):

Try run this command in your project root directory> **./gradlew androiddependencies**
If you find library 'android-query' occurs two times with different versions, you can fix your project's dependency to avoid this problem.